# Not able to save the url in firestore

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

I am using below code to upload the selected image in flutter application to firebase storage, which is done successfully, but I am not able to save the `url` of the pic in firestore, what wrong I am doing in this case?

You can see the attempt to store the url is there in the code below. Please guide how should I correct it?

```
Future uploadFile(String uid) async {

    StorageReference reference = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child('profile_pic/$uid');
    StorageUploadTask uploadTask = reference.putFile(avatarImageFile);
    StorageTaskSnapshot storageTaskSnapshot;
    uploadTask.onComplete.then((value) {
      if (value.error == null) {
        storageTaskSnapshot = value;
        storageTaskSnapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then((downloadUrl) {
          setState(() {
            photoUrl = downloadUrl;

          });
          Firestore.instance
              .collection('users')
              .document(uid)
              .setData({ 'photoUrl': photoUrl}).then((data) async {
            setState(() {
              isLoading = false;
            });
            Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: "Upload success");
          }).catchError((err) {
            setState(() {
              isLoading = false;
            });
            Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: err.toString());
          });
        }, onError: (err) {
          setState(() {
            isLoading = false;
          });
          Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: 'This file is not an image');
        });
      } else {
        setState(() {
          isLoading = false;
        });
        Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: 'This file is not an image');
      }
    }, onError: (err) {
      setState(() {
        isLoading = false;
      });
      Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: err.toString());
    });
  }
```

Comment: @PeterHaddad I got this code from here, in the `settings.dart` file https://github.com/duytq94/flutter-chat-demo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method is already declared asynchronous so try and use `await` instead of `then()`:

```
Future uploadFile(String uid) async {

    StorageReference reference = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child('profile_pic/$uid');
    StorageTaskSnapshot snapshot = await reference.putFile(avatarImageFile).onComplete;
      if (snapshot.error == null) {
        final String photoUrl = await snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
           Firestore.instance
              .collection('users')
              .document(uid)
              .setData({ 'photoUrl': photoUrl}).then((data) async {
            setState(() {
              isLoading = false;
            });
            Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: "Upload success");
          }).catchError((err) {
            setState(() {
              isLoading = false;
            });
            Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: err.toString());
          });
        }, onError: (err) {
          setState(() {
            isLoading = false;
          });
          Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: 'This file is not an image');
        });
      } else {
        setState(() {
          isLoading = false;
        });
        Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: 'This file is not an image');
      }
    }, onError: (err) {
      setState(() {
        isLoading = false;
      });
      Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: err.toString());
    });
  }
```

Now when using `await`, you will be able to retrieve the url first and then save it inside Firestore.

Answer (score 0):

I integrated an upload process in the same way like you did and ran into the same issue, but with javascript instead of doing it in my app.

I think you don't have the download url because there is no promise after your upload process.

```
uploadTask.onComplete.then((value) {
      if (value.error == null) {
        storageTaskSnapshot = value;
        storageTaskSnapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then((downloadUrl) {
          setState(() {
            photoUrl = downloadUrl;

          }); // <------- try to add a .then here 
          Firestore.instance
              .collection('users')
              .document(uid)
              .setData({ 'photoUrl': photoUrl}).then((data) async {
            setState(() {
              isLoading = false;
            });
            Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: "Upload success");
```

I marked the line, continue the function with `then()` so you have the promise. Also make sure to use `awaits` and make firebase functions for uploading process async so you don't ran into strange issues